# How to : Generate bimodal distribuctions

Tags: math, statistics, histogram, distribution

Im working on a problem where i need to work with some bimodal histograms.Like on the example below.

[image: Example of a bimodal histogram]

But im getting hard times looking for them. Im working with histograms as vector, like in the exemplo below. Is there a way to generate random bimodal histograms by any programming language?
(since i can save those histograms to a txt file)

```
Histogram 1
```

8029, 41, 82, 177, 135, 255, 315, 591, 949, 456, 499, 688, 446, 733, 712, 1595, 2633, 3945, 6134, 9755, 9236, 11911, 11888, 9450, 13119, 8819, 5991, 4399, 6745, 2017, 3747, 1777, 2946, 1623, 2151, 454, 3015, 3176, 2211, 1080, 391, 580, 750,

Histogram 2

8082, 4857, 1494, 2530, 1604, 1636, 1651, 1681, 1630, 1667, 1636, 1649, 1934, 1775, 1701, 1691, 1478, 1649, 1449, 1449, 1503, 1475, 1497, 1398, 1509, 1747

Histogram 3

50, 226, 857, 2018, 1810, 1795, 1840, 1929, 1942, 1693, 1699, 1547, 1564, 1556, 1451, 1439, 1448, 1357, 1428, 1419, 1383, 1705, 1670, 1777, 1826, 1865, 1897
.

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize unimodal distributions with the peaks where you want them, and then choose among them with the desired relative proportions.

For instance, with 100k observations the following generating formula:

[image: If( :SelectProbability <= 0.4, Random Exp() * 3, If( :SelectProbability <= 0.6, Random Normal() * 0.5 + 3, Random Normal() + 7 )]

produced this histogram:

[image: Histogram with three modes]

where 40% of the time you generate an exponential with a mean of 3, 20% of the time a N(3, 0.5), and the remainder of the time a N(7,1).

Adjust the distributions, means, standard deviations, and proportions to suit.